# How to avoid absolute positioned text-elements to overlap when reducing windows width?

Tags: css, text, layout, responsive, absolute

I need to create a layout for a project where different text blocks are set to `position: absolute;` inside a column so I can use `display: none;`;  I'm struggling to make it responsive. My text blocks overlap when the window size decreases. I don't want to put text size in `%`.

I'd like my text blocks to follow each other without overlapping. Any hint on how I can solve that?

I've created a explanation schema:

[image]

Comment: Show example of your current code, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a fresh website always use the `reset css` template found here [MeyerWeb Reset Css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This way all the html tags don't have existing `padding` or `margin` on their own and you can style it in your own way.

And when it comes to responsive mode always use `%` in your `div` elements and apply it inside your `media queries`

```
    @media only screen (max-width:600px) { // Specify viewport value to change the look
  .box-right-absolute {width:40%;}
}
```

```css
.wrapper {position:relative;margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:100%;max-width:1200px}

.box-right-absolute {position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:400px;}
.box-sub-right {position:relative;min-height:200px;background:red;color:#fff;padding:20px;margin-bottom:10px;}

@media only screen (max-width:600px) {
  .box-right-absolute {width:40%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="box-right-absolute">
<div class="box-sub-right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Cursus sit amet dictum sit. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac.
</div>
<div class="box-sub-right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Cursus sit amet dictum sit. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```